# How to get counts of the files present in remote directory using sftp command

Tags: shell-script, sftp, echo, wc

I have a sftp server (Dbprd@101.102.130.23). I am trying to connect to it and search for files that contain *.txt* in (/files/base/incomming) path and get the count of lines in each file that contains (.txt). I was trying to achieve with the following command but it's throwing as invalid command:

```
 echo "wc -l *.txt*"|sftp -q Dbprd@101.102.130.23:/files/base/incomming

 o/p
 sftp>
 invalid command
```

Is there any way around to solve this?

Comment: `sftp` doesn't fork a shell on the other end, so you can't use the usual binaries. But if you can use `sftp` can you also use `ssh`?

Comment: Thanak for the response . Yes i can use ssh and sftp over here !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the number of files is not too large, you could use globbing to set the positional parameters to each matching filename, then echo back the count:

```
count=$(ssh Dbprd@101.102.130.23 
        'set -- /files/base/incomming/*.txt; echo "$#"')
```

Or, if the number of files *is* large (but less than [`uintmax_t`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8797120/4957508)), and you have GNU find (for the `-printf` extension), then you could use [a trick I saw from Stéphane](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/299575/117549):

```
count=$(ssh Dbprd@101.102.130.23 
        'find /files/base/incomming -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*.txt' -printf . | wc -c')
```

The above runs the `find` command against the given directory, limiting the depth to just that directory, and also limiting the matches to being plain files (`-type f`) and also whose name ends with `.txt`; for every match, a single period is printed, the total number of which is counted up by `wc -c` and returned from the command substitution into the assignment to `count`.

Answer (score 3):

`sftp` doesn't fork a shell so you can't use your usual commands there. Assuming you also can login through `ssh` you can use

```
ssh Dbprd@101.102.130.23 'ls /files/base/incomming/*.txt' | wc -l
```

or

```
ssh Dbprd@101.102.130.23 'ls /files/base/incomming/*.txt | wc -l'
```

to accomplish the task described in the question.

If (for whatever reason) you want to use `sftp` you need to use one of the commands available within `ftp` (and hope that the `ftpd` on the other side knows how to handle wildcards):

```
echo 'ls -l /files/base/incomming/*.txt' | sftp Dbprd@101.102.130.23 | wc -l
```

Comment: `touch $'file\nname.txt'` causes this to fail (increases the count by mistakenly counting the embedded newline in the filename)

Comment: @JeffSchaller Indeed :-) The OP was asking for how to run a specific command over {sftp,ssh} though, not how to harden it against borderline cases. If all else fails there is always `ssh ... find -print0 ...`

Comment: It's good to point out the limitations, of course -- just like you did with sftp; the command-set inside (s)ftp is limited.  Alternatives come to mind like mounting the remote filesystem over ssh, with sshfs: [example 1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/202919/117549), [example 2](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/9250/117549)